# Is this expected behaviour for 'remove from all unlinked collections'?

Tags: collections

[image]

I executed 'remove from all unlinked collections' command on a cube and the active object disappeared in viewport and I found it in orphan data. I tried to move the orphan object to scene collection but failed. Does this command have a bug?

Answer (score 3):

Did you try dragging the orphaned object from the Outliner back into the 3D View?

[image]

*sorry for the low quality*